# adobe brackets beautify css or less

Tags: css, plugins, less, line, adobe-brackets

I use plugin brackets-beautify for adobe brackets 
https://github.com/Hirse/brackets-beautify

I have these options for css:

```
"css": {
    "eol": "\n",
    "end_with_newline": true,
    "selector_separator_newline": true,
    "newline_between_rules": true
},
```

But when I beautify less file:

```
&__item:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bdbdbd 20%, #d8d8d8);
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

&__link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

I get

```
&__item:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bdbdbd 20%, #d8d8d8);
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
&__link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

but I want to save new line inside rule. Do you have any suggestions how I can do it. Thank You.

I tried to add

```
"preserve_newlines": true,
"max_preserve_newlines": 1,
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: I use the same plugin and I haven't your problem, with `"newline_between_rules": true` there is a line between classes, if I set `false` there isn't any line

Comment: Yes, I have new line in top level rules, but have not inside not top level rules ...

Comment: ah ok, I think is not possible, is the same problem with the `@media` rules, the code inside mediaqueries don't respect the line